# Сохранение объекта после перезагрузки

Tags: android, объекты

Я создаю свой объект, в процессе работы программы его поля меняются. Есть ли способ сохранить значения этих полей и состояния объекта до следующей загрузки приложения?
`SharedPreferences` сохраняет только `boolean`, `int`, `float`, `String`.

Есть ли способ сохранить объект в памяти телефона, а потом прочитать при следующем запуске?

Comment: Сереализуйте объект в строку?

Comment: можете поподробнее с ссылками и комментариями? как вы поняли у меня объект наследник FrameLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов много.

1. `ObjectOutputStream`.
2. Сериализация в строку (есть куча готовых сериализаторов в XML и JSON, например) с последующей записью в файл или `SharedPreferences`.
3. БД.

Comment: 1. Попробовал сделать с ObjectOutputStream, выскочило NotSerializableException. Объект у меня FrameLayout с добавленными в него вьюшками. Это исключение выпало потому, что объект FrameLayout нельзя серилизовать? Может я что-то не учел? Код при необходимости приведу.
2. Можете поделиться ссылками, слету не получилось найти.

Comment: 1. Не пытайтесь сериализовать `View` или что-то, содержащее `Context`. Сериализуйте модели.
2. GSON, Jackson, SimpleXML, etc.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под моделью?
я попробовал запихнуть framelayout в класс с интерфейсом Serializable. Ошибка такая же.

Comment: Вы, очевидно, не читали мой комментарий выше? `FrameLayout` — это тоже `View`, как ни странно.

Comment: Я это прочитал, и естественно у меня не вышло сериализовать FrameLayout. Можете рассказать про модель?

Comment: Вы, я так понимаю, хотите сохранять состояние какого-то `View`? Так вынесите это состояние в отдельную сущность, которая и будет сохраняться и восстанавливаться.

Answer (score 1):

[Хранение данных в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104038/)

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет библиотека [Android Complex Preferences](https://github.com/fsilvestremorais/android-complex-preferences)